# Global high score system for Android

Tags: android

I'm looking for a simple high score system I can use for an Android Game I'm developing. The user should submit a username and the score. That's it.

There are already many similar questions here, some of which are many years old. The solutions suggested there do not exist anymore as far as I can see:

- ScoreNinja: Gone
- Skiller: Gone
- SwarmConnect: I can reach the website, but when I click the "Sign Up" Button, nothing happens. So I guess it's gone as well?
- OpenFeint: Gone

I can store high scores locally via SQLite, that wasn't a big problem. If there's no other solution, I will look into how to send this data to a server. But I would prefer a "ready-made" solution for this.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to include google play services, but this might help
[Leaderboards in Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've already looked into this and this might be the solution in the end. I just wanted to know if there's a solution without a Google Sign-In.